# Calling API from custom button Magento2

Tags: magento2

I need to call an Rest API on clicking a button in magento2 . I have placed the button in product page but i need to call an api while clicking that button

Here is the button code in view

```
<a class="custom-button" > Click Now </a>
```

On clicking this button i should call an external  REST API , How to do this

Answer (score 0):

You need to do following things.

1. On the Above `Button` click call the `Ajax Function`.
2. On that `Ajax Function` you can call the `API with the URL` which you want to call.
3. After Calling, it return the `result` and you can do the further things according to your requirements.